# Keep the same mode value for all rows in a group

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe with `df['type'].unique() = [0,1,2,3]`.
I want to group the dataframe with the date and find the most occurring digit and then create a column for the entire group with the same value group. I've used mode() and tried to create a column but only the first row of the group gets the value.

e.g.:

```
Date           Type
01-02-2021     0
02-02-2021     1
03-02-2021     2
04-02-2021     1
05-02-2021     1
01-03-2021     2
02-03-2021     2
03-03-2021     1
04-03-2021     2
05-03-2021     1
```

What I need is:

```
Date           Type    Most_OCCURING
01-02-2021     0       1
02-02-2021     1       1
03-02-2021     2       1
04-02-2021     1       1
05-02-2021     1       1
01-03-2021     2       2
02-03-2021     2       2
03-03-2021     1       2
04-03-2021     2       2
05-03-2021     1       2
```

Comment: Please post the code you've used to get your result.

Comment: why is the  most_occuring value for ```03-03-2021```  2 and not 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `df.mode()` returns a `pandas.Series`. If you just want to assign the first mode value to the column, you can do:

```
>>> df.groupby("Date")["Type"].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), as follows:

```
df['Most_OCCURING'] = df.groupby('Date')['Type'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
```